# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, database-connection

I have launched my site in IIS 7.5.There was an issue in the site and i tried to solve it.after doing the changes i build the solution and tried to check out in the site.At that time i got an exception details as

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'"

this is the source error

```
Line 25:        /// <param name="dataTable"><see>System.Data.DataTalbe</see> a rellenar</param>
Line 26:         public void FillTable(System.Data.DataTable dataTable) 
                 { 
                     this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];       
                      this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                 }
```

Can anyone help me with the solution?

Comment: Check that you use the correct password and your server use sql authentication, and finally don't use sa account as @podiluska wrote.

Answer (score 8):

For starters, **don't run your solution using the sa account**!

Create an account with the permissions your app requires, and use that.  Put the connection string in the `ConnectionStrings` section of  `web.config`

Answer (score 0):

Keeping **Trusted_Connection=True** solves my issue in connection string